# Django unable to read variable specified in form action

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me with the below? I'm reading 'how to tango with django' project and stuck here.

I want a html form to revert back to a view function(add_page).

```
  <h1>Add a Page</h1>
    {% if category %}
    <form id="category_form" method="post" action="/rango/category/{{category.slug}}/add_page/">
    {% endif %}
```

This is my url map

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^about/$',views.about, name = 'about'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',views.category,name = 'category'),
    url(r'^add_category/$', views.add_category, name = 'add_category'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/$',views.add_page, name ='add_page'),
    )
```

and my veiws.add_page function

```
def add_page(request,category_name_slug):

    try:
        cat = Category.objects.get(slug = category_name_slug)
    except :
        cat = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if cat:
                page = form.save(commit = False)
                page.category = cat
                page.views = 0
                page.save()
                return redirect('/rango')
        else:
            print (form.errors)

    else:
        form = PageForm()

    context_dict = {'form':form,'category':cat}

    return render(request, 'rango/add_page.html',context_dict)
```

the submit button doesnt seem to be taking to post data to the requested url. Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm the `add_page` function is being called when you submit data? Maybe add in the rest of your `urls.py` file.

Comment: Did you look inside the generated HTML? Does the form gets rendered correctly?

Comment: @Matcher - Yes , the form seems to rendering as It should

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to the same page 
you should probably call

```
return redirect('add_page', category_name_slug=page.category)
```

or maybe use something like

```
return redirect(request.build_absolute_uri())
```

in the POST section of your code.

[request methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#methods)

[redirect() options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

EDIT: To clarify the 'return redirect('rango/')' is not pointing to anything in the url mapping in the question.

Comment: I thought I should redirect once the form POST data gets validated. Once validated , isn't it better to redirect the user to the main page as opposed to redirecting to the same page?

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to redirect when you have handled a POST in a view. Where you redirect after that is up to you, I cannot determine what is best for your application. If you use redirect, make sure it's part of your url map, for instance return redirect('index')